# How to have session array variables in PHP with same name in shopping cart?

Tags: php, session

I am creating a shopping cart in PHP using session variables to store the users product selections prior to checking out. For the most part, it works. The problem is that if a user selects lets say a 'red' shirt in size 'small', it adds it to the session variable as

```
    'products' =>
    array(size=1)
        'code' =>
            array(size=5)
                'product_size' => string 'Small'
                'quantity' => string '1'
                'product_code' => string 'sku'
                'name' => string 'shirt red'
                'price' => string '25'
```

**BUT** if the user selects the same item in a different size, it overwrites the previous session variable with same code.

How can I make it so the user can get the same item in different sizes without overwriting the previous session variable?

Comment: short answer, yes,long answer it depends

Comment: You would probably need to make each product code use arrays vs strings.

Comment: you need to wrap it in an array, `[products => ['shirt product' =>[ [redshirt], [blueshirt] ] ] ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build it like this

```
 ['products' => [
    $sku => [  //the actual sku value, not literally sku
        'price' => '25', //if it's common ( total = price x total_qty ), if not put a total here
         //'total_price' => 70
        'total_qty' => 3,
        'name' => string 'shirt red' //if its common
        'items' => [
             0 => [
                 'size' => 'Small'
                 'quantity' => '1'              
                 //'price' => 20
             ], 1 => [ 
                 'size' => 'Medium'
                 'quantity' => '2'              
                 //'price' => '25' 
             ]   
        ] //end items
   ]//end sku
]
```

Basically nest an item with the stuff is different for each item.  I put price in commented form if its not common to the sizes.

You could also key the items on size if that is the main difference like this

```
  .....
   'items' => [
        'Small' => [
             'quantity' => '1'              
             //'price' => 20
         ], 'Medium' => [ 
             'quantity' => '2'              
             //'price' => '25' 
         ]   
    ]
```

This is less "flexible" but easier to minimize duplicate items. The `items` array keys are easier to check then a further nested 'size' key.

This should give you the idea, the actual structure is up to you and your use case,  build it in the way that allows you the easiest access to the items, but is still flexible enough to accommodate all your products.

Last example, if the size and quantity are the only things that are different you could even do away with the nested array.

```
.....
'items' => [
    'Small' => '1','Medium' => '2'  
 ]
```

Also your array has this obvious error in your question.

```
   product_color' => string 'Small'
```

Comment: How would I pass that on to PayPal for purchase completion? I'm new to creating a shopping cart and didn't really want to do it but my client insisted that I be the one to construct it. Feels I could complete the challenge. This is the example I am using [here](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/07/php-multiple-items-shopping-cart-integration-with-paypal)

Comment: paypal probably doesn't care what size it is only the quantity and price.  But it depends on what `Paypal` API you are using.  You probably cant and would have to iterate though your cart sending it to paypal using their API.  Honestly I haven't setup a checkout in about 6 years, as most can be done with something like WooCommerce etc.

Comment: @SteveC. - essential your cart and what PayPal need to know are 2 different things, it depends if the `receipt` your customer gets comes from paypal or you.  Because the minimum is paypal just wants the total to charge the customer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That'll put me in the right direction. I know how I have to do it now.

Comment: Thanks! I'm self taught and have been coding for over 12 years but there's still lots out there for me to learn. This client that I've been working with for the last 3 years likes to challenge me to force me to learn it. Being a disabled vet, this is the only thing that brings me joy.

Comment: Cool man I can relate, I am self taught too, but i went to school for webdesign ( only light coding there ).  Been doing PHP 7 years, I'm a CIO ( Chief Information Officer ) I probably write up to 20k lines of code a day...  Creating stuff is the essence of humanity.

Answer (score 1):

Keep product id as key and inside that have the attributes such as name, sku and types.

```
[
'products' => [
    'pid123' => [
        [
            'name' => 'abc',
            'sku' => 'sku-abc',
            'types' => [
                [
                    'colour' => 'red',
                    'size' => '42',
                    'qty' => 1
                ],
                [
                    'colour' => 'red',
                    'size' => '40',
                    'qty' => 2
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'pid789' => [
        [
            'name' => 'xyz',
            'sku' => 'sku-xyz',
            'types' => [
                [
                    'colour' => 'red',
                    'size' => '42',
                    'qty' => 1
                ],
                [
                    'colour' => 'red',
                    'size' => '40',
                    'qty' => 2
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ] 
]];
```

Type list will contain various size, colour, and quantity information.